# C++ exception in 'nativeFlushQueueImmediate' - react-native, bitcore-lib

Tags: android, react-native, bitcore

I got the exception below, any solutions?

```
 E/ReactNativeJS(29997): C++ exception in 'nativeFlushQueueImmediate'
 E/ReactNativeJS(29997): E/ReactNativeJS(29997): Malformed calls from
 JS: field sizes are different. E/ReactNativeJS(29997):
 E/ReactNativeJS(29997):
 [[3,27],[0,0],[[141,100,1540362732403,false]],592]
```

This image showing error i face it 
[image]

Comment: anyone have answer???